# Blur event triggers automatically when assigning value conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, laravel-5, blur

I'm calling a function on blur event of a < textarea >.

**HTML: (Laravel blade template)**

```
<textarea class="form-control" required>{{ isset($assessment_params[$parameter->id]) ? $assessment_params[$parameter->id] : NULL }}</textarea>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('blur', 'textarea', function() {
        alert('Blur event triggered');
    });
});
```

**Issue:**

The blur event for that < textarea > triggers as soon as I visit the page. It should only trigger when I lost focus from that textarea(like standard blur event).

I figure out that issue occurs when I'm assignging value conditionaly for that < textarea >.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('textarea').on('blur', function(){
        alert('Blur event triggered');
    });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66bw5u4h/86/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. yes, that did the trick. However can you please explain that what was wrong in the JS code? Why on() on document is not working as expected?

Comment: **Explanation:** on() is used for dynamic binding of events to listeners. Here there is no need of using on() first. second if on() is used then never used it using document as it will listen for each and every event fired on document. In your case it is listening to every blur() done on document. 

Enjoy the coding :)

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will bind the blur event with the class contains 'form_control'

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.form-control').bind('blur', function() {
    alert('Blur event triggered');
 });
});
```